# If I install a Linux VM, will I be able to work with ext filesystems from my Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine, filesystems, raspberry-pi

I'm working from a Mac and need to [edit a few lines on a Linux partition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/4444/10113). (I need to enable SSH on Raspbian for a Raspberry Pi, but I need to do so effectively headless – I don't have any peripherals that I can use with the device.)  I have been working with [OSXFuse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/140536/82179) and trying to get it to work, but I've been unsuccessful.

I was wondering if I could install a virtual machine on OSX and then use a Linux on this VM to make my edits.  My caution is that VMs are, to my understanding, slightly abstracted from the hardware.  That is, the hardware the VM sees is not necessarily the hardware the host has.  Will I be able to make edits this way, or must I find some other workaround?

The partition I need to access is on an SD card.

If this is possible, *how* can I use this method?

Comment: i'm sure you can, though i don't have osx and this link doesn't give a howto http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-manage-ext2ext3-disks-in-os-x/   A more intelligent question would be HOW you connect the host HDD to your Guest OS. Maybe via networking of guest OS and host OS. I hope somebody can provide more of a howto in their answer.

Comment: @barlop Well, now that I know it's possible, the *how* is a natural next step :) Thanks for the link!